# Detect emoticons in string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, detection, emoticons

I found that you need PHP 7 and MySQL 5.5 to use emoticons in a string that you want to upload to the database. 
I don't have these specification on my server so I want to give an error message in laravel or php.

Is there a way to detect emoticons in php? If so then I can create a custom validation or something like that?

I've tried `alpha_dash` validation in Laravel but then it isn't possible to do one old-school like this one `:-)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148690/removing-emojis-from-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing emojis from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148690/removing-emojis-from-variable)

Comment: I don't want to remove them but detect them 

Comment: The answer of the question contains a regex as a response, so you could easily use it for your case...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To follow on from Johannes answer I found a solution on a forum somewhere. This regex does the trick :)

```
    $unicodeRegexp = '([*#0-9](?>\\xEF\\xB8\\x8F)?\\xE2\\x83\\xA3|\\xC2[\\xA9\\xAE]|\\xE2..(\\xF0\\x9F\\x8F[\\xBB-\\xBF])?(?>\\xEF\\xB8\\x8F)?|\\xE3(?>\\x80[\\xB0\\xBD]|\\x8A[\\x97\\x99])(?>\\xEF\\xB8\\x8F)?|\\xF0\\x9F(?>[\\x80-\\x86].(?>\\xEF\\xB8\\x8F)?|\\x87.\\xF0\\x9F\\x87.|..(\\xF0\\x9F\\x8F[\\xBB-\\xBF])?|(((?<zwj>\\xE2\\x80\\x8D)\\xE2\\x9D\\xA4\\xEF\\xB8\\x8F\k<zwj>\\xF0\\x9F..(\k<zwj>\\xF0\\x9F\\x91.)?|(\\xE2\\x80\\x8D\\xF0\\x9F\\x91.){2,3}))?))';
```

Comment: what is the ?> extension. it cause error :|

Comment: for closing php script

Answer (score 9):

This is shamelessly copied and adjusted from this function [here](https://gist.github.com/hnq90/316f08047a3bf348b823). So kudos to [Huy Nguyen Quang](https://gist.github.com/hnq90) who has written the original function.

```
function has_emojis_old( $string ) {

    preg_match( '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u', $string, $matches_emo );

    return !empty( $matches_emo[0] ) ? true : false;

}
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out there are some emojis that the above function do not detect. I've checked that and thats absolutely right.

Reason for that is that the function above checks an unicode range (similar to: is this character between 5 and 15). But there are many emojis that aren't in this range. It would be possible to just increase the unicode range but maybe there are some characters in that range that aren't emojis … so that seems not very elegant.

The original function checks multiple ranges and this may be the best solution. Thing is, this function was updated 4 years ago so it certainly do not reflect the current emoji palette.

Because im not very into emojis and their unicode ranges i can't provide a range based solution … instead i just check against [all existing emoji unicodes](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html):

```
function has_emojis( $string ) {

    // Array of emoji (v12, 2019) unicodes from https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html

    $unicodes = array( '1F600','1F603','1F604','1F601','1F606','1F605','1F923','1F602','1F642','1F643','1F609','1F60A','1F607','1F970','1F60D','1F929','1F618','1F617','263A','1F61A','1F619','1F60B','1F61B','1F61C','1F92A','1F61D','1F911','1F917','1F92D','1F92B','1F914','1F910','1F928','1F610','1F611','1F636','1F60F','1F612','1F644','1F62C','1F925','1F60C','1F614','1F62A','1F924','1F634','1F637','1F912','1F915','1F922','1F92E','1F927','1F975','1F976','1F974','1F635','1F92F','1F920','1F973','1F60E','1F913','1F9D0','1F615','1F61F','1F641','2639','1F62E','1F62F','1F632','1F633','1F97A','1F626','1F627','1F628','1F630','1F625','1F622','1F62D','1F631','1F616','1F623','1F61E','1F613','1F629','1F62B','1F971','1F624','1F621','1F620','1F92C','1F608','1F47F','1F480','2620','1F4A9','1F921','1F479','1F47A','1F47B','1F47D','1F47E','1F916','1F63A','1F638','1F639','1F63B','1F63C','1F63D','1F640','1F63F','1F63E','1F648','1F649','1F64A','1F48B','1F48C','1F498','1F49D','1F496','1F497','1F493','1F49E','1F495','1F49F','2763','1F494','2764','1F9E1','1F49B','1F49A','1F499','1F49C','1F90E','1F5A4','1F90D','1F4AF','1F4A2','1F4A5','1F4AB','1F4A6','1F4A8','1F573','1F4A3','1F4AC','1F441','FE0F','200D','1F5E8','FE0F','1F5E8','1F5EF','1F4AD','1F4A4','1F44B','1F91A','1F590','270B','1F596','1F44C','1F90F','270C','1F91E','1F91F','1F918','1F919','1F448','1F449','1F446','1F595','1F447','261D','1F44D','1F44E','270A','1F44A','1F91B','1F91C','1F44F','1F64C','1F450','1F932','1F91D','1F64F','270D','1F485','1F933','1F4AA','1F9BE','1F9BF','1F9B5','1F9B6','1F442','1F9BB','1F443','1F9E0','1F9B7','1F9B4','1F440','1F441','1F445','1F444','1F476','1F9D2','1F466','1F467','1F9D1','1F471','1F468','1F9D4','1F471','200D','2642','FE0F','1F468','200D','1F9B0','1F468','200D','1F9B1','1F468','200D','1F9B3','1F468','200D','1F9B2','1F469','1F471','200D','2640','FE0F','1F469','200D','1F9B0','1F469','200D','1F9B1','1F469','200D','1F9B3','1F469','200D','1F9B2','1F9D3','1F474','1F475','1F64D','1F64D','200D','2642','FE0F','1F64D','200D','2640','FE0F','1F64E','1F64E','200D','2642','FE0F','1F64E','200D','2640','FE0F','1F645','1F645','200D','2642','FE0F','1F645','200D','2640','FE0F','1F646','1F646','200D','2642','FE0F','1F646','200D','2640','FE0F','1F481','1F481','200D','2642','FE0F','1F481','200D','2640','FE0F','1F64B','1F64B','200D','2642','FE0F','1F64B','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9CF','1F9CF','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9CF','200D','2640','FE0F','1F647','1F647','200D','2642','FE0F','1F647','200D','2640','FE0F','1F926','1F926','200D','2642','FE0F','1F926','200D','2640','FE0F','1F937','1F937','200D','2642','FE0F','1F937','200D','2640','FE0F','1F468','200D','2695','FE0F','1F469','200D','2695','FE0F','1F468','200D','1F393','1F469','200D','1F393','1F468','200D','1F3EB','1F469','200D','1F3EB','1F468','200D','2696','FE0F','1F469','200D','2696','FE0F','1F468','200D','1F33E','1F469','200D','1F33E','1F468','200D','1F373','1F469','200D','1F373','1F468','200D','1F527','1F469','200D','1F527','1F468','200D','1F3ED','1F469','200D','1F3ED','1F468','200D','1F4BC','1F469','200D','1F4BC','1F468','200D','1F52C','1F469','200D','1F52C','1F468','200D','1F4BB','1F469','200D','1F4BB','1F468','200D','1F3A4','1F469','200D','1F3A4','1F468','200D','1F3A8','1F469','200D','1F3A8','1F468','200D','2708','FE0F','1F469','200D','2708','FE0F','1F468','200D','1F680','1F469','200D','1F680','1F468','200D','1F692','1F469','200D','1F692','1F46E','1F46E','200D','2642','FE0F','1F46E','200D','2640','FE0F','1F575','1F575','FE0F','200D','2642','FE0F','1F575','FE0F','200D','2640','FE0F','1F482','1F482','200D','2642','FE0F','1F482','200D','2640','FE0F','1F477','1F477','200D','2642','FE0F','1F477','200D','2640','FE0F','1F934','1F478','1F473','1F473','200D','2642','FE0F','1F473','200D','2640','FE0F','1F472','1F9D5','1F935','1F470','1F930','1F931','1F47C','1F385','1F936','1F9B8','1F9B8','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9B8','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9B9','1F9B9','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9B9','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9D9','1F9D9','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9D9','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9DA','1F9DA','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9DA','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9DB','1F9DB','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9DB','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9DC','1F9DC','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9DC','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9DD','1F9DD','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9DD','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9DE','1F9DE','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9DE','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9DF','1F9DF','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9DF','200D','2640','FE0F','1F486','1F486','200D','2642','FE0F','1F486','200D','2640','FE0F','1F487','1F487','200D','2642','FE0F','1F487','200D','2640','FE0F','1F6B6','1F6B6','200D','2642','FE0F','1F6B6','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9CD','1F9CD','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9CD','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9CE','1F9CE','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9CE','200D','2640','FE0F','1F468','200D','1F9AF','1F469','200D','1F9AF','1F468','200D','1F9BC','1F469','200D','1F9BC','1F468','200D','1F9BD','1F469','200D','1F9BD','1F3C3','1F3C3','200D','2642','FE0F','1F3C3','200D','2640','FE0F','1F483','1F57A','1F574','1F46F','1F46F','200D','2642','FE0F','1F46F','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9D6','1F9D6','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9D6','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9D7','1F9D7','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9D7','200D','2640','FE0F','1F93A','1F3C7','26F7','1F3C2','1F3CC','1F3CC','FE0F','200D','2642','FE0F','1F3CC','FE0F','200D','2640','FE0F','1F3C4','1F3C4','200D','2642','FE0F','1F3C4','200D','2640','FE0F','1F6A3','1F6A3','200D','2642','FE0F','1F6A3','200D','2640','FE0F','1F3CA','1F3CA','200D','2642','FE0F','1F3CA','200D','2640','FE0F','26F9','26F9','FE0F','200D','2642','FE0F','26F9','FE0F','200D','2640','FE0F','1F3CB','1F3CB','FE0F','200D','2642','FE0F','1F3CB','FE0F','200D','2640','FE0F','1F6B4','1F6B4','200D','2642','FE0F','1F6B4','200D','2640','FE0F','1F6B5','1F6B5','200D','2642','FE0F','1F6B5','200D','2640','FE0F','1F938','1F938','200D','2642','FE0F','1F938','200D','2640','FE0F','1F93C','1F93C','200D','2642','FE0F','1F93C','200D','2640','FE0F','1F93D','1F93D','200D','2642','FE0F','1F93D','200D','2640','FE0F','1F93E','1F93E','200D','2642','FE0F','1F93E','200D','2640','FE0F','1F939','1F939','200D','2642','FE0F','1F939','200D','2640','FE0F','1F9D8','1F9D8','200D','2642','FE0F','1F9D8','200D','2640','FE0F','1F6C0','1F6CC','1F9D1','200D','1F91D','200D','1F9D1','1F46D','1F46B','1F46C','1F48F','1F469','200D','2764','FE0F','200D','1F48B','200D','1F468','1F468','200D','2764','FE0F','200D','1F48B','200D','1F468','1F469','200D','2764','FE0F','200D','1F48B','200D','1F469','1F491','1F469','200D','2764','FE0F','200D','1F468','1F468','200D','2764','FE0F','200D','1F468','1F469','200D','2764','FE0F','200D','1F469','1F46A','1F468','200D','1F469','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F469','200D','1F467','1F468','200D','1F469','200D','1F467','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F469','200D','1F466','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F469','200D','1F467','200D','1F467','1F468','200D','1F468','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F468','200D','1F467','1F468','200D','1F468','200D','1F467','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F468','200D','1F466','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F468','200D','1F467','200D','1F467','1F469','200D','1F469','200D','1F466','1F469','200D','1F469','200D','1F467','1F469','200D','1F469','200D','1F467','200D','1F466','1F469','200D','1F469','200D','1F466','200D','1F466','1F469','200D','1F469','200D','1F467','200D','1F467','1F468','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F466','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F467','1F468','200D','1F467','200D','1F466','1F468','200D','1F467','200D','1F467','1F469','200D','1F466','1F469','200D','1F466','200D','1F466','1F469','200D','1F467','1F469','200D','1F467','200D','1F466','1F469','200D','1F467','200D','1F467','1F5E3','1F464','1F465','1F463','1F9B0','1F9B1','1F9B3','1F9B2','1F435','1F412','1F98D','1F9A7','1F436','1F415','1F9AE','1F415','200D','1F9BA','1F429','1F43A','1F98A','1F99D','1F431','1F408','1F981','1F42F','1F405','1F406','1F434','1F40E','1F984','1F993','1F98C','1F42E','1F402','1F403','1F404','1F437','1F416','1F417','1F43D','1F40F','1F411','1F410','1F42A','1F42B','1F999','1F992','1F418','1F98F','1F99B','1F42D','1F401','1F400','1F439','1F430','1F407','1F43F','1F994','1F987','1F43B','1F428','1F43C','1F9A5','1F9A6','1F9A8','1F998','1F9A1','1F43E','1F983','1F414','1F413','1F423','1F424','1F425','1F426','1F427','1F54A','1F985','1F986','1F9A2','1F989','1F9A9','1F99A','1F99C','1F438','1F40A','1F422','1F98E','1F40D','1F432','1F409','1F995','1F996','1F433','1F40B','1F42C','1F41F','1F420','1F421','1F988','1F419','1F41A','1F40C','1F98B','1F41B','1F41C','1F41D','1F41E','1F997','1F577','1F578','1F982','1F99F','1F9A0','1F490','1F338','1F4AE','1F3F5','1F339','1F940','1F33A','1F33B','1F33C','1F337','1F331','1F332','1F333','1F334','1F335','1F33E','1F33F','2618','1F340','1F341','1F342','1F343','1F347','1F348','1F349','1F34A','1F34B','1F34C','1F34D','1F96D','1F34E','1F34F','1F350','1F351','1F352','1F353','1F95D','1F345','1F965','1F951','1F346','1F954','1F955','1F33D','1F336','1F952','1F96C','1F966','1F9C4','1F9C5','1F344','1F95C','1F330','1F35E','1F950','1F956','1F968','1F96F','1F95E','1F9C7','1F9C0','1F356','1F357','1F969','1F953','1F354','1F35F','1F355','1F32D','1F96A','1F32E','1F32F','1F959','1F9C6','1F95A','1F373','1F958','1F372','1F963','1F957','1F37F','1F9C8','1F9C2','1F96B','1F371','1F358','1F359','1F35A','1F35B','1F35C','1F35D','1F360','1F362','1F363','1F364','1F365','1F96E','1F361','1F95F','1F960','1F961','1F980','1F99E','1F990','1F991','1F9AA','1F366','1F367','1F368','1F369','1F36A','1F382','1F370','1F9C1','1F967','1F36B','1F36C','1F36D','1F36E','1F36F','1F37C','1F95B','2615','1F375','1F376','1F37E','1F377','1F378','1F379','1F37A','1F37B','1F942','1F943','1F964','1F9C3','1F9C9','1F9CA','1F962','1F37D','1F374','1F944','1F52A','1F3FA','1F30D','1F30E','1F30F','1F310','1F5FA','1F5FE','1F9ED','1F3D4','26F0','1F30B','1F5FB','1F3D5','1F3D6','1F3DC','1F3DD','1F3DE','1F3DF','1F3DB','1F3D7','1F9F1','1F3D8','1F3DA','1F3E0','1F3E1','1F3E2','1F3E3','1F3E4','1F3E5','1F3E6','1F3E8','1F3E9','1F3EA','1F3EB','1F3EC','1F3ED','1F3EF','1F3F0','1F492','1F5FC','1F5FD','26EA','1F54C','1F6D5','1F54D','26E9','1F54B','26F2','26FA','1F301','1F303','1F3D9','1F304','1F305','1F306','1F307','1F309','2668','1F3A0','1F3A1','1F3A2','1F488','1F3AA','1F682','1F683','1F684','1F685','1F686','1F687','1F688','1F689','1F68A','1F69D','1F69E','1F68B','1F68C','1F68D','1F68E','1F690','1F691','1F692','1F693','1F694','1F695','1F696','1F697','1F698','1F699','1F69A','1F69B','1F69C','1F3CE','1F3CD','1F6F5','1F9BD','1F9BC','1F6FA','1F6B2','1F6F4','1F6F9','1F68F','1F6E3','1F6E4','1F6E2','26FD','1F6A8','1F6A5','1F6A6','1F6D1','1F6A7','2693','26F5','1F6F6','1F6A4','1F6F3','26F4','1F6E5','1F6A2','2708','1F6E9','1F6EB','1F6EC','1FA82','1F4BA','1F681','1F69F','1F6A0','1F6A1','1F6F0','1F680','1F6F8','1F6CE','1F9F3','231B','23F3','231A','23F0','23F1','23F2','1F570','1F55B','1F567','1F550','1F55C','1F551','1F55D','1F552','1F55E','1F553','1F55F','1F554','1F560','1F555','1F561','1F556','1F562','1F557','1F563','1F558','1F564','1F559','1F565','1F55A','1F566','1F311','1F312','1F313','1F314','1F315','1F316','1F317','1F318','1F319','1F31A','1F31B','1F31C','1F321','2600','1F31D','1F31E','1FA90','2B50','1F31F','1F320','1F30C','2601','26C5','26C8','1F324','1F325','1F326','1F327','1F328','1F329','1F32A','1F32B','1F32C','1F300','1F308','1F302','2602','2614','26F1','26A1','2744','2603','26C4','2604','1F525','1F4A7','1F30A','1F383','1F384','1F386','1F387','1F9E8','2728','1F388','1F389','1F38A','1F38B','1F38D','1F38E','1F38F','1F390','1F391','1F9E7','1F380','1F381','1F397','1F39F','1F3AB','1F396','1F3C6','1F3C5','1F947','1F948','1F949','26BD','26BE','1F94E','1F3C0','1F3D0','1F3C8','1F3C9','1F3BE','1F94F','1F3B3','1F3CF','1F3D1','1F3D2','1F94D','1F3D3','1F3F8','1F94A','1F94B','1F945','26F3','26F8','1F3A3','1F93F','1F3BD','1F3BF','1F6F7','1F94C','1F3AF','1FA80','1FA81','1F3B1','1F52E','1F9FF','1F3AE','1F579','1F3B0','1F3B2','1F9E9','1F9F8','2660','2665','2666','2663','265F','1F0CF','1F004','1F3B4','1F3AD','1F5BC','1F3A8','1F9F5','1F9F6','1F453','1F576','1F97D','1F97C','1F9BA','1F454','1F455','1F456','1F9E3','1F9E4','1F9E5','1F9E6','1F457','1F458','1F97B','1FA71','1FA72','1FA73','1F459','1F45A','1F45B','1F45C','1F45D','1F6CD','1F392','1F45E','1F45F','1F97E','1F97F','1F460','1F461','1FA70','1F462','1F451','1F452','1F3A9','1F393','1F9E2','26D1','1F4FF','1F484','1F48D','1F48E','1F507','1F508','1F509','1F50A','1F4E2','1F4E3','1F4EF','1F514','1F515','1F3BC','1F3B5','1F3B6','1F399','1F39A','1F39B','1F3A4','1F3A7','1F4FB','1F3B7','1F3B8','1F3B9','1F3BA','1F3BB','1FA95','1F941','1F4F1','1F4F2','260E','1F4DE','1F4DF','1F4E0','1F50B','1F50C','1F4BB','1F5A5','1F5A8','2328','1F5B1','1F5B2','1F4BD','1F4BE','1F4BF','1F4C0','1F9EE','1F3A5','1F39E','1F4FD','1F3AC','1F4FA','1F4F7','1F4F8','1F4F9','1F4FC','1F50D','1F50E','1F56F','1F4A1','1F526','1F3EE','1FA94','1F4D4','1F4D5','1F4D6','1F4D7','1F4D8','1F4D9','1F4DA','1F4D3','1F4D2','1F4C3','1F4DC','1F4C4','1F4F0','1F5DE','1F4D1','1F516','1F3F7','1F4B0','1F4B4','1F4B5','1F4B6','1F4B7','1F4B8','1F4B3','1F9FE','1F4B9','1F4B1','1F4B2','2709','1F4E7','1F4E8','1F4E9','1F4E4','1F4E5','1F4E6','1F4EB','1F4EA','1F4EC','1F4ED','1F4EE','1F5F3','270F','2712','1F58B','1F58A','1F58C','1F58D','1F4DD','1F4BC','1F4C1','1F4C2','1F5C2','1F4C5','1F4C6','1F5D2','1F5D3','1F4C7','1F4C8','1F4C9','1F4CA','1F4CB','1F4CC','1F4CD','1F4CE','1F587','1F4CF','1F4D0','2702','1F5C3','1F5C4','1F5D1','1F512','1F513','1F50F','1F510','1F511','1F5DD','1F528','1FA93','26CF','2692','1F6E0','1F5E1','2694','1F52B','1F3F9','1F6E1','1F527','1F529','2699','1F5DC','2696','1F9AF','1F517','26D3','1F9F0','1F9F2','2697','1F9EA','1F9EB','1F9EC','1F52C','1F52D','1F4E1','1F489','1FA78','1F48A','1FA79','1FA7A','1F6AA','1F6CF','1F6CB','1FA91','1F6BD','1F6BF','1F6C1','1FA92','1F9F4','1F9F7','1F9F9','1F9FA','1F9FB','1F9FC','1F9FD','1F9EF','1F6D2','1F6AC','26B0','26B1','1F5FF','1F3E7','1F6AE','1F6B0','267F','1F6B9','1F6BA','1F6BB','1F6BC','1F6BE','1F6C2','1F6C3','1F6C4','1F6C5','26A0','1F6B8','26D4','1F6AB','1F6B3','1F6AD','1F6AF','1F6B1','1F6B7','1F4F5','1F51E','2622','2623','2B06','2197','27A1','2198','2B07','2199','2B05','2196','2195','2194','21A9','21AA','2934','2935','1F503','1F504','1F519','1F51A','1F51B','1F51C','1F51D','1F6D0','269B','1F549','2721','2638','262F','271D','2626','262A','262E','1F54E','1F52F','2648','2649','264A','264B','264C','264D','264E','264F','2650','2651','2652','2653','26CE','1F500','1F501','1F502','25B6','23E9','23ED','23EF','25C0','23EA','23EE','1F53C','23EB','1F53D','23EC','23F8','23F9','23FA','23CF','1F3A6','1F505','1F506','1F4F6','1F4F3','1F4F4','2640','2642','2695','267E','267B','269C','1F531','1F4DB','1F530','2B55','2705','2611','2714','2716','274C','274E','2795','2796','2797','27B0','27BF','303D','2733','2734','2747','203C','2049','2753','2754','2755','2757','3030','00A9','00AE','2122','0023','FE0F','20E3','002A','FE0F','20E3','0030','FE0F','20E3','0031','FE0F','20E3','0032','FE0F','20E3','0033','FE0F','20E3','0034','FE0F','20E3','0035','FE0F','20E3','0036','FE0F','20E3','0037','FE0F','20E3','0038','FE0F','20E3','0039','FE0F','20E3','1F51F','1F520','1F521','1F522','1F523','1F524','1F170','1F18E','1F171','1F191','1F192','1F193','2139','1F194','24C2','1F195','1F196','1F17E','1F197','1F17F','1F198','1F199','1F19A','1F201','1F202','1F237','1F236','1F22F','1F250','1F239','1F21A','1F232','1F251','1F238','1F234','1F233','3297','3299','1F23A','1F235','1F534','1F7E0','1F7E1','1F7E2','1F535','1F7E3','1F7E4','26AB','26AA','1F7E5','1F7E7','1F7E8','1F7E9','1F7E6','1F7EA','1F7EB','2B1B','2B1C','25FC','25FB','25FE','25FD','25AA','25AB','1F536','1F537','1F538','1F539','1F53A','1F53B','1F4A0','1F518','1F533','1F532','1F3C1','1F6A9','1F38C','1F3F4','1F3F3','1F3F3','FE0F','200D','1F308','1F3F4','200D','2620','FE0F','1F1E6','1F1E8','1F1E6','1F1E9','1F1E6','1F1EA','1F1E6','1F1EB','1F1E6','1F1EC','1F1E6','1F1EE','1F1E6','1F1F1','1F1E6','1F1F2','1F1E6','1F1F4','1F1E6','1F1F6','1F1E6','1F1F7','1F1E6','1F1F8','1F1E6','1F1F9','1F1E6','1F1FA','1F1E6','1F1FC','1F1E6','1F1FD','1F1E6','1F1FF','1F1E7','1F1E6','1F1E7','1F1E7','1F1E7','1F1E9','1F1E7','1F1EA','1F1E7','1F1EB','1F1E7','1F1EC','1F1E7','1F1ED','1F1E7','1F1EE','1F1E7','1F1EF','1F1E7','1F1F1','1F1E7','1F1F2','1F1E7','1F1F3','1F1E7','1F1F4','1F1E7','1F1F6','1F1E7','1F1F7','1F1E7','1F1F8','1F1E7','1F1F9','1F1E7','1F1FB','1F1E7','1F1FC','1F1E7','1F1FE','1F1E7','1F1FF','1F1E8','1F1E6','1F1E8','1F1E8','1F1E8','1F1E9','1F1E8','1F1EB','1F1E8','1F1EC','1F1E8','1F1ED','1F1E8','1F1EE','1F1E8','1F1F0','1F1E8','1F1F1','1F1E8','1F1F2','1F1E8','1F1F3','1F1E8','1F1F4','1F1E8','1F1F5','1F1E8','1F1F7','1F1E8','1F1FA','1F1E8','1F1FB','1F1E8','1F1FC','1F1E8','1F1FD','1F1E8','1F1FE','1F1E8','1F1FF','1F1E9','1F1EA','1F1E9','1F1EC','1F1E9','1F1EF','1F1E9','1F1F0','1F1E9','1F1F2','1F1E9','1F1F4','1F1E9','1F1FF','1F1EA','1F1E6','1F1EA','1F1E8','1F1EA','1F1EA','1F1EA','1F1EC','1F1EA','1F1ED','1F1EA','1F1F7','1F1EA','1F1F8','1F1EA','1F1F9','1F1EA','1F1FA','1F1EB','1F1EE','1F1EB','1F1EF','1F1EB','1F1F0','1F1EB','1F1F2','1F1EB','1F1F4','1F1EB','1F1F7','1F1EC','1F1E6','1F1EC','1F1E7','1F1EC','1F1E9','1F1EC','1F1EA','1F1EC','1F1EB','1F1EC','1F1EC','1F1EC','1F1ED','1F1EC','1F1EE','1F1EC','1F1F1','1F1EC','1F1F2','1F1EC','1F1F3','1F1EC','1F1F5','1F1EC','1F1F6','1F1EC','1F1F7','1F1EC','1F1F8','1F1EC','1F1F9','1F1EC','1F1FA','1F1EC','1F1FC','1F1EC','1F1FE','1F1ED','1F1F0','1F1ED','1F1F2','1F1ED','1F1F3','1F1ED','1F1F7','1F1ED','1F1F9','1F1ED','1F1FA','1F1EE','1F1E8','1F1EE','1F1E9','1F1EE','1F1EA','1F1EE','1F1F1','1F1EE','1F1F2','1F1EE','1F1F3','1F1EE','1F1F4','1F1EE','1F1F6','1F1EE','1F1F7','1F1EE','1F1F8','1F1EE','1F1F9','1F1EF','1F1EA','1F1EF','1F1F2','1F1EF','1F1F4','1F1EF','1F1F5','1F1F0','1F1EA','1F1F0','1F1EC','1F1F0','1F1ED','1F1F0','1F1EE','1F1F0','1F1F2','1F1F0','1F1F3','1F1F0','1F1F5','1F1F0','1F1F7','1F1F0','1F1FC','1F1F0','1F1FE','1F1F0','1F1FF','1F1F1','1F1E6','1F1F1','1F1E7','1F1F1','1F1E8','1F1F1','1F1EE','1F1F1','1F1F0','1F1F1','1F1F7','1F1F1','1F1F8','1F1F1','1F1F9','1F1F1','1F1FA','1F1F1','1F1FB','1F1F1','1F1FE','1F1F2','1F1E6','1F1F2','1F1E8','1F1F2','1F1E9','1F1F2','1F1EA','1F1F2','1F1EB','1F1F2','1F1EC','1F1F2','1F1ED','1F1F2','1F1F0','1F1F2','1F1F1','1F1F2','1F1F2','1F1F2','1F1F3','1F1F2','1F1F4','1F1F2','1F1F5','1F1F2','1F1F6','1F1F2','1F1F7','1F1F2','1F1F8','1F1F2','1F1F9','1F1F2','1F1FA','1F1F2','1F1FB','1F1F2','1F1FC','1F1F2','1F1FD','1F1F2','1F1FE','1F1F2','1F1FF','1F1F3','1F1E6','1F1F3','1F1E8','1F1F3','1F1EA','1F1F3','1F1EB','1F1F3','1F1EC','1F1F3','1F1EE','1F1F3','1F1F1','1F1F3','1F1F4','1F1F3','1F1F5','1F1F3','1F1F7','1F1F3','1F1FA','1F1F3','1F1FF','1F1F4','1F1F2','1F1F5','1F1E6','1F1F5','1F1EA','1F1F5','1F1EB','1F1F5','1F1EC','1F1F5','1F1ED','1F1F5','1F1F0','1F1F5','1F1F1','1F1F5','1F1F2','1F1F5','1F1F3','1F1F5','1F1F7','1F1F5','1F1F8','1F1F5','1F1F9','1F1F5','1F1FC','1F1F5','1F1FE','1F1F6','1F1E6','1F1F7','1F1EA','1F1F7','1F1F4','1F1F7','1F1F8','1F1F7','1F1FA','1F1F7','1F1FC','1F1F8','1F1E6','1F1F8','1F1E7','1F1F8','1F1E8','1F1F8','1F1E9','1F1F8','1F1EA','1F1F8','1F1EC','1F1F8','1F1ED','1F1F8','1F1EE','1F1F8','1F1EF','1F1F8','1F1F0','1F1F8','1F1F1','1F1F8','1F1F2','1F1F8','1F1F3','1F1F8','1F1F4','1F1F8','1F1F7','1F1F8','1F1F8','1F1F8','1F1F9','1F1F8','1F1FB','1F1F8','1F1FD','1F1F8','1F1FE','1F1F8','1F1FF','1F1F9','1F1E6','1F1F9','1F1E8','1F1F9','1F1E9','1F1F9','1F1EB','1F1F9','1F1EC','1F1F9','1F1ED','1F1F9','1F1EF','1F1F9','1F1F0','1F1F9','1F1F1','1F1F9','1F1F2','1F1F9','1F1F3','1F1F9','1F1F4','1F1F9','1F1F7','1F1F9','1F1F9','1F1F9','1F1FB','1F1F9','1F1FC','1F1F9','1F1FF','1F1FA','1F1E6','1F1FA','1F1EC','1F1FA','1F1F2','1F1FA','1F1F3','1F1FA','1F1F8','1F1FA','1F1FE','1F1FA','1F1FF','1F1FB','1F1E6','1F1FB','1F1E8','1F1FB','1F1EA','1F1FB','1F1EC','1F1FB','1F1EE','1F1FB','1F1F3','1F1FB','1F1FA','1F1FC','1F1EB','1F1FC','1F1F8','1F1FD','1F1F0','1F1FE','1F1EA','1F1FE','1F1F9','1F1FF','1F1E6','1F1FF','1F1F2','1F1FF','1F1FC','1F3F4','E0067','E0062','E0065','E006E','E0067','E007F','1F3F4','E0067','E0062','E0073','E0063','E0074','E007F','1F3F4','E0067','E0062','E0077','E006C','E0073','E007F' );

    return preg_match( '/[\x{' . implode( '}\x{', $unicodes ) . '}]/u', $string ) ? true : false;

}
```

This function has – of course – to be updated for every new emoji release but that has to happen for ranged solutions as well.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't detect some emoji's eg Heart (❤️), Sun ()

Comment: Altough this are the exact characters from the unicode emoji table it seems to have problem with numbers and/or other characters … any suggestions or a working solution for all existing emojis would be great. Haven't found a good solution so far

Comment: This works well. But it removes numbers as well (e.g. 12345). How should I update the preg_match to allow numbers to remain in the string?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function:

```
function remove_emoji($string) {

    // Match Emoticons
    $regex_emoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
    $regex_symbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
    $regex_transport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
    $regex_misc = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Dingbats
    $regex_dingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);

    return $clear_string;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are really discouraged. To help future readers, please explain what you are doing too!

Comment: This doesn't seem to catch flags 

Answer (score 2):

You can detect emoji below code:

```
function hasEmoji($string)
{
    $emojis_regex =
        '/[\x{0080}-\x{02AF}'
        .'\x{0300}-\x{03FF}'
        .'\x{0600}-\x{06FF}'
        .'\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}'
        .'\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}'
        .'\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}'
        .'\x{2000}-\x{209F}'
        .'\x{20D0}-\x{214F}'
        .'\x{2190}-\x{23FF}'
        .'\x{2460}-\x{25FF}'
        .'\x{2600}-\x{27EF}'
        .'\x{2900}-\x{29FF}'
        .'\x{2B00}-\x{2BFF}'
        .'\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}'
        .'\x{2E00}-\x{2E7F}'
        .'\x{3000}-\x{303F}'
        .'\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}'
        .'\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}'
        .'\x{FE00}-\x{FE0F}'
        .'\x{FE30}-\x{FE4F}'
        .'\x{1F000}-\x{1F02F}'
        .'\x{1F0A0}-\x{1F0FF}'
        .'\x{1F100}-\x{1F64F}'
        .'\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}'
        .'\x{1F910}-\x{1F96B}'
        .'\x{1F980}-\x{1F9E0}]/u';
    preg_match($emojis_regex, $string, $matches);
    return !empty($matches);
}

hasEmoji('Happy birth day'); // false
hasEmoji('Happy birth day '); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to detect them and not extract them, perhaps try the following.

```
$string = "some string from wherever ..";
$encstr = rawurlencode($string);
$stat = strpos($encstr,"%F0") !== false ? "Has emoji" : "No emoji.";
echo $stat;
```

Obviously change the output to suit your situation.

All the other solutions on this page missed some emojis in my testing, but this solution has detected all that I've tested so far.

It's possible that there might be false positives that you might need to watch out for.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$emojis_regex = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}\x{2700}-\x{27BF}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}\x{24C2}-\x{1F251}\x{1F30D}-\x{1F567}\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}\x{1FA70}-\x{1FAF6}]/u';

preg_match($emojis_regex, $string, $matches);

if (!empty($matches)) {
    echo "has Emoji " . $string;
} else {
    echo "doesn't have Emoji " . $string;
}
```

Here is the list of emojis that covered with this regular expression https://regex101.com/r/LdYElj/1

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to store string as encoded unicode and decode it when you access it like so:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @final
 */
trait DescriptionTrait
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return \utf8_decode($this->description);
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $description
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = \utf8_encode($description);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to detect an emoji is to use the Symbol property in the Unicode regex option.

```
preg_match('/\p{S}/u', $string, $output);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Welcome, thanks for your insight & documentation link. Might I suggest an `edit` to refrain from using absolute definitive such as "the best way" in your answers. *Rarely* is there only 1 definitive "best" way that is fail safe for every situation. *Personally* I see that as a likely flag for either a toxic ego, a new inexperienced programmer, or both (*Of course there are always exceptions!*) If there are *any* caveats, or instances where this method may fail, it'd be good to notate them, especially with "best" claim. Eg: environment/language code is run in, or the character set being parsed.

Comment: This also detects "Symbols" like "+" and "="