# How to distinguish and separate any two or more Emojis which were accepted as a string using PHP?

Tags: php, emoji

For example, I have

```
$string="\xF0\x9F\x91\x8E\xF0\x9F\x91\x8E\xF0\x9F\x91\x8E";

//three thumbs-up emoji
```

How to find out what Emojis were accepted and separate them?

Comment: What is "accepted"?

Comment: It means I took someone's message and converted it to string

Comment: Sidenote: that's a thumbs-down emoji, not thumbs-up.

Comment: Related? [Detect emoticons in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580483/detect-emoticons-in-string).

Comment: Okay, I'm using Bot Telegram API, And I receive a message from a user converted to the string. This string may contain Emojis, and I should return a certain response on certain Emoji. That's why I need to find all 
Emojis from user's message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [**emoji-detector-php**](https://github.com/aaronpk/emoji-detector-php) and it is very helpful and easy to use.

```
From the DOCS:

$input = "Hello  World ‍‍‍";
$emoji = Emoji\detect_emoji($input);

print_r($emoji);
```