# How can I detect usage of graphical unicode characters (smileys and other) in input field parameter?

Tags: php, unicode, character

I have a search page on my website, and when I read logs, I can found some spam queries, usually for drugs, and using graphical Unicode characters.
[image: search page logs]

How can I detect this characters? I want to blacklist ips using there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing emojis from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148690/removing-emojis-from-variable)

Comment: I will check it soon.

Comment: Do you think i can only check \xEE and \xEF or is it too generic ?